# Why does the super assignment not work with a tibble in r?

Tags: r, assign, assignment-operator, tibble

I'm just starting to use tibbles and am finding some quirks.  For example, the following code give the error 'Error: cannot change value of locked binding for 'a'.

```
library (tidyverse)
a <<- tibble (aa=1)
```

However, the following code works.

```
library (tidyverse)
b <- tibble (bb=1)
b <<- b
```

Is this a bug or a feature I don't understand about tibbles?

Comment: can you give us more precisions? if I run the first code it totally works for me.

Comment: Your code also executes without error for me. Try restarting your R session and see if the behavior continues to occur. `packageVersion("tibble") [1] ‘3.0.1’`

Comment: Yes, it also work for me. Here there is a good explanation of the `<<-` operator: https://thomasadventure.blog/posts/what-does-the-operator-do/

Comment: You're correct.  After restarting r, the error no longer occurs.